# What is the difference between "yet", "as yet" and "so far" in negative sentences?

Tags: difference

Could you tell me what the difference is between *yet*, *as yet* and *so far* in negative sentences For example:

> I have a whole cake, but I haven't touched it **yet**.
>
> I have a whole cake, but I haven't touched it **as yet**.
>
> I have a whole cake, but I haven't touched it **so far**.

Comment: It's purely a stylistic choice whether to precede ***yet*** by ***as*** when used adverbially ***after*** the relevant main verb ("touched", here). If you move that element to between the auxiliary and the main verb *(I haven't **as yet** touched it)*, you ***can*** include ***as***, but if you move it even further forwards to before the main verb *(I **as yet** haven't touched it)*, you ***must***. That sequence is far less likely though.  And although it's perfectly okay to move ***as yet*** forward like that, this doesn't work at all well with ***so far***. Semantically, they're identical.

Comment: I wouldn't use _as yet_ in conversation. It's a rather formal expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use 'not as yet' and 'not so far' when in expectation or hope of something happening, or if work is underway on something but it has not yet been completed or the goal achieved.

For example:

- Police are seeking witnesses but **so far** nobody has come forward.
- A search is underway for the missing person but **as yet** he has not been found.

By contrast, when we say that something has simply 'not happened yet' it can mean that no work or effort has begun to make it happen. This seems most appropriate in your example of a cake where either you have touched it, or you haven't.

Answer (score -1):

yet:

> meaning you will eat it sooner or later

as yet:

> meaning until now or a particular time in the past.

so far can mean two things

> Pills can only take you so far

meaning it helps you to a certain level but does not fully help you

Or:

> I haven't eaten it so far

meaning you haven't eaten it up until now

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So I take it "so far" and "as yet" mean exactly the same thing, right?

Comment: yes 'as yet' can mean 'yet' or 'so far' depending on what your sentence is sir.